# Ajax success JSON html output loop - Results displaying for Nano-second only

Tags: jquery, html, arrays, json, ajax

Ajax request that returns an array in a JSON format. Loop through the returned array to spit out entries from one of the columns and display using html divs.

Problem is the results only display on the webpage for a nano-second and then disappear.

Do I need prevent default in there? Are the curly brackets etc in the correct places?

JQuery snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":submit").click(function(e){
        var msg = $("#search").val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'search.php',
            method:'POST',
            data:{
                msg:msg
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {

            for( var key of Object.keys( response ) ) {
            $( '.content' ).append( `<div class="post"><div class="post-text">${response[key].MessageText}</div></div>` );

                }
             }
        });  
    });  
});
```

Html:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="on"><pre>

<input name="msg" id="search" type="text" autofocus value= "<?php if(isset($_POST['msg'])) { 
 echo htmlentities ($_POST['msg']); }?>"></input> <span id="error"></span>

<input type="submit" id="submit" style="border:0; padding:0; font-size:0">

</pre></form>

<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: I guess you see the values there for a short period of time because once you submit it is refreshing the page in the browser in the same time.

Comment: @norbitrial that makes sense. :)

Comment: If you still need help then if you post the HTML element what jQuery found for `:submit`, happy to help.

Comment: Thank you @norbitrial much appreciated. Have added the html code to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example.

```
$(function() {
  $(":submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'search.php',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        msg: $("#search").val()
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(response) {
        $.each(response, function(i, v) {
          var p = $("<div>", {
            class: "post item-" + i
          }).appendTo($(".content"));
          $("<div>", {
            class: "post-text"
          }).html(v.messageText).appendTo(p);
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

To prevent the form from submitting you want to apply `.preventDefault()` on the event. This will ensure that your code gets run and the form submit the data by default.

Comment: Thank you. So adding the .preventdefault() allows the search results to stay on the page but if I type a new search term the page does not change; the old results just remain on the page. @norbitrial

Comment: @CGarden then you need to clear the old results before appending new ones. Add `$(".content").html("");` before the `$.each()` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Technically the issue is when you click on `submit` then it refreshes the page and that's why you see the DOM change just for a short period of time.

Maybe you can try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":submit").click(function(e) {
        var msg = $("#search").val();
        $.ajax({
           // ajax call details
        });

        // this step should stop refreshing the page
        e.preventDefault();
    });  
});
```

From [`event.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) documentation:

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help, I've added a note to the first answer.